# batch file to create a numbered list and print to text

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

How can I have a batch file that will ask Name:

Then print that name to a text file **1 - 150** times depending on the 
amount of times I'd like the name printed to a text file in order:

Ex.

```
Name:
Number of Times:
Printing to text file

Mike 1
Mike 2 
Mike 3
```

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P uname=Please enter your name: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
ECHO %uname%
pause
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter your name! Bye bye!!
Pause
```

I need it to ask me how many times to print name to text file test.txt

Comment: `set /?` (especially `set /p`), `for /?` (especially `for /L`), and `echo`.

Comment: Ok figured it out.  Thanks Stephan for the (for /L)  thats what I needed. Now I just need it to write the info to a text file and my visual basic app will become 75% less tedious with all the names I need!    Please mark solved

Comment: I am having a hard time getting this to print to a text file, here is what I am trying to use: ECHO %uname% %%G >C:\Users\admin\Documents\name.txt  - but all it prints to the name.txt file is Mike 150.  The output of the console shows the right thing and that is Mike 1 Mike 2 Mike 3 etc...What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks again.

Comment: the redirection `>` overwrites your file every time. Use `>>` to append to a file.

Comment: Thank you so much again Stephan - I was using the >> but I dont think I saved the change when I tried it.  I saved the change this time and it works just as I needed it to!  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P uname=Please enter your name:
SET /P count=How many lines:
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%count%) DO ECHO %uname% %%G >>C:\Users\admin\Documents\name1.txt
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
pause
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter your name! Bye bye!!
```

This allows you to print to a text file any name and the number of times you want that name printed.  Im using this to help me in a vb app when it comes to editing items in a dropdown list. Its a Audio Bible Study app and some of the books of the bible have alot of chapters - for ex. Psalms has 150 chapters.  So this script allows me to print Psalms with each chapter to a text file and then I can copy paste the output to my dropdown list instead of having to type Psalms 1 Psalms 2 Psalms 3 etc... Each dropdown Item when clicked gives the Dramatized Audio for that Chapter!.  Thanks again Stephan for all your help.

Comment: you can have it ask you `set /p count=How many lines: ` and then `for /L %%G in (1,1,%count%) do ... `

Comment: Omg!  Thank you again Stephan for making my other project in vb so much easier now that I have this batch file.  The improved code works way better and I can put any name in and any number.  Thank you!

Comment: Stephan, added a :START and GOTO line so it would ask me again for another name and how many times - my question is how would I get it to print to a new text file instead of the same text file when I put new info in?

Comment: echo to `>>"C:\Users\admin\Documents\%uname%.txt"`. (The quotes `"` are not really required here, but help if there is a space in the path or name.) By the way: if you `goto end`, there should be an `:end` label too - or you use `goto :eof`. `:eof` is a "build in label" and means "go to the very end of the batch file".  You can also use `"%userprofile%\Documents\%uname%.txt"`, if you want to use it on different Computers or Users.